# Is there a way to 'remove' a field during a mongo aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Is there a way to remove a field during an aggregation? 
I have a result that looks like this:

```
{
"firstName":"Patient1",
"lastName":"last",
"addresses":[
    {
     "street1":"1011 Happy Lane",
     "street2":"Apt 1",
    },
],
"phone":"11111111"
}
```

I am trying to exclude 'addresses' from the result:

```
{
"firstName":"Patient1",
"lastName":"last",
"phone":"11111111"
}
```

I found $unset but only seems to work on update.

Also I don't want to manually 'group' the other items because I need to return everything but the attributes I want to exclude. Selectively adding seems very easy in aggregation but selectively removing seems a bit more involved. Appreciate any ideas here.

Comment: Does `$project: { fieldYouDontWant: 0 }` ex:  `$project: { addresses: 0 }` not work? That should return everything minus the field mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `$project` stage in your pipeline. You have two options available to you when using a projection.

The first is you can whitelist the returned fields by specifying the fields you want to include with a value of `1`. The projection stage would look something like this:

```
{ $project: {
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 1,
    phone: 1
}}
```

The second is you can blacklist the returned fields by specifying the fields you don't want to include with a value of `0`. The projection stage would look something like this:

```
{ $project: {
    addresses: 0
}}
```

Both approaches have their merits and which one you should use depends largely on your use case. A good rule of thumb is that if you will only ever want certain fields and don't want to modify your projection stage when new fields are added, you should use a whitelist approach, but if you only want to exclude certain fields while allowing any new fields to be included in the results, you should use a blacklist approach.